# Upgrade Nifi from 1.13.2-alpine to 1.15.3-alpine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-nifi, alpine-linux

I have created a custom Dockerfile of Nifi-1.13.2 with `Alpine-3.14.2` as the base image and I want to upgrade it to Nifi-1.15.3 with `Alpine-3.15.0` as the base image  but I get error related to sensitive properties when I deploy the image in a pod on my Kubernetes setup even though the image works fine without any errors when run locally on my machine. The init-container is terminated properly but the main container logs shows the error.

I have a set of 4 files for kubernetes:- `nifi-secret.yaml`, `nifi-service.yaml`, `nifi-configmap.yaml`, and `nifi-statefuleset.yaml`. The sensitive properties have been set and the setup was working fine with `Nifi-1.13.2`. How can I solve this issue?

[Nifi pod logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD3bZ.png)

[Base Alpine custom Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZAmV.png)

[Nifi Dockerfile part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxOk3.jpg)

[Nifi Dockerfile part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhym.jpg)

Comment: A Dockerfile is plain text, not a multi-part PNG file; I can't read or run the Dockerfiles you've attached to the question.  Can you [edit] the question to include all of the relevant details as text (not images) directly in the question (not behind links)?  If the setup is extensive to try reduce it to a [mcve] first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any volume mount PVC or NFS in deployment?

Nifi official doc states that it generates random keys when `nifi.sensitive.props.key` is empty from version 1.14 however you are migrating from 1.13 to 1.15.

Ref doc : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#nifi_sensitive_props_key

You can also check out this bug issue you need to update the start.sh file and resolve the issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8943

replacing line in **start.sh**

```
prop_replace 'nifi.sensitive.props.key'   "${NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY:-}"
```

Changes you could apply in **start.sh**

```
if [ -n "${KEY}" ]; then
    prop_replace 'nifi.sensitive.props.key' "${KEY}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I added in my nifi-statefulset.yaml file: `prop_replace nifi.sensitive.props.key mysenstivkey /tmp/conf/nifi.properties` and it worked perfectly fine. This is the only change I made in my statefulset.yaml file when migrating from Nifi-1.13.2_alpine to Nifi-1.15.3_alpine.